# PIVOT cut by multiple value string

Tags: excel, pivot, powerpivot

I have a problem when trying to pivot some data, which for ex. looks like this:

```
ID NAME USER     TYPE     LABEL
1  test testuser typetest "label1,label2,label3"
```

Now I can slice the data by user or type, but I also have to do it by "label". And label has many values separated by ",". I could not find a way to add a label slicer.

What I tried - creating a new table with structure like this:

```
ID LABEL
1  label1
1  label2
1  label3
```

and linking them, using relationship but this would not work and the pivot would not care about the slicer.

What would be the best way for me to insert slicer by label in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: you'll need to go the path you started going, but not link the tables. create a new singular table with one row for each label and all the other associated data, then pivot on that table.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman thanks for the reply, that is what I tried actually. The problem is that now there are many duplicates in the data, where only "label" is different. So when I do COUNT or SUM on other columns, I get incorrect results. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Are you using the PowerPivot addin for Excel or just using a standard Excel pivot table? If the former, you could handle this easily in a DAX measure, but it is not clear what your scenario is.

Comment: I think I'm using PowerPivot addon for this one. Maybe you could give me an example, how to calculate average by the label so this would not count the duplicates? Thanks!